# How to use CSS variables with Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Is it possible to use CSS variables with Tailwind CSS?
For instance, let's say I have these variables:

```
--primary-color: #fff;
--secondary-color: #000;
```

And I would like to use them in Tailwind like so:

```
<div class="bg-primary-color">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Assuming you have already added TailwindCSS to your project and that your CSS file is called `global.css`.

First, you need to edit `global.css` to look like this:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

.root,
#root,
#docs-root {
  --primary-color: #fff;
  --secondary-color: #000;
}
```

And then, in order to be able to use them, you need to update `tailwind.config.js` with the new CSS variables like so:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        "primary-color": "var(--primary-color)",
        "secondary-color": "var(--secondary-color)"
      },
    },
  },
};
```

You can now use these variables as desired:

```
<div class="bg-primary-color">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This is my preferred solution, but it does have a downside: it doesn't automatically integrate with Tailwind's Dark Mode support. You have to add a media query (or class if you're using class-based dark mode) around the `root` rule to get that.

Comment: in my case I had to add :root selector to the global css for the variables

Answer (score 78):

Now Tailwind supports CSS custom properties as [arbitrary values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#resolving-ambiguities) since v3.0.

```css
:root {
  --text-color: red;
  --text-size: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<span class="text-[color:var(--text-color)] text-[length:var(--text-size)] font-bold">
  Hello world!
</span>
```

Comment: Annoying thing is I have to define the data type every time which also makes it look really bloated but yeah at least it works.

Comment: @Thielicious you can use a media query on the root element to support media dark mode, which would accomplish the same thing. You can also use a class on the :root element if youre using the .dark approach.

Answer (score 76):

Armando's answer didn't work for me but with this change it did work.

`global.css`:

no need to target a class or id. you can target the root itself using the Pseudo-Selector
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_root.asp

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

:root {
  --primary-color: #fff;
  --secondary-color: #000;
}
```

as for `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        "primary-color": "var(--primary-color)",
        "secondary-color": "var(--secondary-color)"
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: It took me a minute to realize that `var` in also inside the string.

Comment: This won't work if you try to change the color opacity. Example: `bg-primary/50`

Answer (score 8):

If you want your variables to work with the opacity modifier syntax, you'll need to defined them as follows:

```
:root {
  --color-primary: 255 115 179;
  --color-secondary: 111 114 185;
}
```

Then use them in your config:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      // Using modern `rgb`
      primary: 'rgb(var(--color-primary) / <alpha-value>)',
      secondary: 'rgb(var(--color-secondary) / <alpha-value>)',

      // Using modern `hsl`
      primary: 'hsl(var(--color-primary) / <alpha-value>)',
      secondary: 'hsl(var(--color-secondary) / <alpha-value>)',
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, you'll need to convert your hex colors to rgb before you use them. Otherwise, they won't work properly. Here's the link to the documentation: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#using-css-variables

Answer (score 5):

You can easily configure it using this plugin. (supports darkMode) https://github.com/mertasan/tailwindcss-variables

```
npm install -D @mertasan/tailwindcss-variables
```

#### Usage:

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
        red: {
            50: 'var(--colors-red-50)'
        }
    }
    variables: {
      DEFAULT: {
        sizes: {
          small: '1rem',
          button: {
            size: '2rem'
          }
        },
        colors: {
          red: {
            50: '#ff3232',
          },
        },
      },
      '.container': {
        sizes: {
          medium: '1.5rem',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@mertasan/tailwindcss-variables')
  ]
}
```

**Output:**

```css
:root {
  --sizes-small: 1rem;
  --sizes-button-size: 2rem;
  --colors-red-50: #ff3232
}

.container {
  --sizes-medium: 1.5rem
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that css variables was not built into tailwind at some point. I'm using tailwindcss@2.2.4 and I'm able to reference css variables without this plugin.

Answer (score 2):

```js
You can use font family CSS variables with Tailwind CSS by following these steps:

Define your font family CSS variables in a global CSS file, such as global.css, and target the root element or a custom selector. For example:
:root {
  --font-sans: "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  --font-serif: "Georgia", "Times New Roman", serif;
}
Update your tailwind.config.js file to include the font family CSS variables under the theme.fontFamily property. For example:
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      sans: "var(--font-sans)",
      serif: "var(--font-serif)",
    },
  },
};
Use the font family CSS variables as desired in your HTML elements with Tailwind classes. For example:
<div className="font-sans">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Alternatively, use CSS var's with a JS framework:**

When I was working with Tailwind and Svelte for the first time, I was looking for a solution to this, and I found that you can use the **style** attribute:

```
<script>
let cssVariables = {
  'primary-color': "#ffffff", 
  'secondary-color': "#000"
}

let styleValues = Object.entries(cssVariables)
.map(([key, value]) => `--${key}:${value}`)
.join(';')
</script>

<p style={styleValues} 
class="text-center text-[4vmax] text-[color:var(--primary-color)]">
  Hello World
</p>
```

The code above makes a object, this object is converted to a string that works like pure CSS, every property is joined to that string.
This works, assuming that you're in Svelte, although, in HTML doesn't.
If you want to use Tailwind with HTML, you must write the whole string:

```
<p style="--primary-color:#ffffff;--secondary-color:#000"
class="text-[4vmax] text-center text-[color:var(--primary-color)]">
  Hello World
</p>
```

So, I recommend you use a framework that help you use data binding. Also, there're other things that you can do with this trick, like reactive CSS (below, in the Svelte way):

```
<script>
$: changingHue = 0
setInterval(() => changing_hue++, 250)
$: cssVariables = {
  'primary-color': `hsl(${changingHue} 100% 70%)`, 
  'secondary-color': "#000"
}

$: styleValues = Object.entries(cssVariables)
.map(([key, value]) => `--${key}:${value}`)
.join(';')
</script>

<p style={styleValues} 
class="text-center text-[4vmax] text-[color:var(--primary-color)]">
  Hello World
</p>
```

In conclusion, you don't need another library to make Tailwind use CSS variables, just Javascript and even HTML is enough.

Comment: mixing the CSS and the JS should be a least resort since it's doable with css only

Comment: @petitkriket Yes, in a simple project, CSS and it's variables would be enough