# How to use colors in tailwind css or material ui in css/scss

Tags: css, sass, material-ui, materialize, tailwind-css

I found this [tailwind color](https://tailwindcolor.com/) for tailwind css and for the [material ui colors](https://materialui.co/colors). These have nicely named color from 100 - 900 and A100 - 400 just like font. I think it would nice to use them directly on scss or css file. How would I do that/ is there a import file I can use?

Comment: You could access them easily in a scss/css file if they are css variables. Sadly by default it's not the case but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64872861/how-to-use-css-variables-with-tailwind-css) gives a way to achieve it.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to use [LESS with TailWindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#less) to benefit from [Mixin](https://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature).

Using **Stylus**:

```
// index.styl
$codeBackground = theme('colors.pink.800')

a
 @apply text-yellow-600 !important
 background $codeBackground !important
```

**Output**:
[image]

Comment: thanks.  I have couple of question.do you have to import some thing in index.styl for theme('colors.pink.800') to work? and would just npm install for less would make it available in my regular html/scss ?

Comment: about stylus I found it working in my test without tailwind base;
tailwind components;
tailwind utilities;
 about less not tested yet in my end. see [less] (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#less)

Comment: i don't have time right now to try if it working..but thanks for you efforts to answer

Comment: don't forget to check answer as solution.

Comment: What about SCSS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. You can just refer to the color classes in markup like..

`bg-blue-400` or `text-red-800`

Comment: I am trying to use these colors in regular css color/background-color attributes it is much easier than writing and referring to the hex codes...

Comment: Ah I see, I think you need to use PostCSS for that

Comment: how would you do that?

Answer (score -6):

First  choose rgb in the dropdown -[image: Step 1]

Then click on any color you want. Its rgb code will be copied. Then use it anywhere in your css file without any hassle ex - color: rgb(146, 64, 14), background-color: rgb(146, 64, 14) etc.

Comment: Did the answer help?

Comment: I you do not ping anybody, they will not be notified but you (on your answer).

Comment: What do u mean??