# Modify CSS variable with Tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

**Variable in index.css :**

```
:root {
    --property: 1;
}
```

**Normal way changing it in CSS on hover:**

```
img{
    transform: scale(var(--property));;
}


.another-element:has(:hover, :focus) 
{
    --property: 1.1;
}
```

**It is possible to attach a variable in Tailwind, but how to modify it? Here is how I attach it to an element :**

```
<img className='scale-x-[var(--property]' src="..." />

<div className='hover:CHANGE-HERE-THE-VARIABLE'>
```

I tried search how to modify it, but I did not found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the variable in main css file and make some chanes in `tailwind.config.js` file.
You can refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64872862/14224876