# How can I dynamically generate the color of a class using Tailwind?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to dynamically generate the color of a tailwind class based on a user selection in React, such as className=`hover:bg-[${color}]` where color can be any as specified by the user (basically any in the RGB range). The goal is to create a custom theme for a web app based on user preference.

I have done my research and found that Tailwind does not support dynamic classes, however the alternatives such as safelisting and trying different static classes approaches have not worked for me. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe keeping the color in a css variable is an option. This might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64872861/how-to-use-css-variables-with-tailwind-css

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use CSS variables with Tailwind CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64872861/how-to-use-css-variables-with-tailwind-css)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for the replies, I do not know if I am missing something but if I were to take this approach I would need to save a variable for every single color as the user of the application can choose any arbitrary color, I think my question was confusing as I specified one hex color (just modified it for it to be clearer), however the color could be any as specified by the user.

Comment: You would need a variable for as many things as can ... vary. You can combine those variables in classes however you want though.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider applying `background-color` using the `style` attribute like:

```
<div style={{ backgroundColor: hex_color }}>
```

For use with Tailwind variants, consider applying `background-color` via a CSS variable:

```
<div
  data-state="active"
  class="data-[state=active]:bg-[--foo]"
  style={{ '--foo': hex_color }}
>
```

(Use `bg-[var(--foo)]` for Tailwind versions less than `v3.3`).

Comment: Everywhere the background-color needs to be used? Talk about a pain to maintain. Also, what's the point of using CSS then, if you're going to style everything inline?

Comment: You would not need to use `background-color` everywhere – you would need to use it where a dynamic value is used. CSS is used to change the presentation of elements, to display them how you'd like. You don't need to inline everything, but at least the dynamic values should be, since as you have found out, Tailwind does not support dynamic classes.

Comment: You don't need dynamic classes, and you don't need to inline anything. Just use a simple CSS custom property (a.k.a. variable).

Comment: This was an option as I can dynamically do what I want using the style attribute, however I want to do it in tailwind as I need to use it based on state, such as data-[state=active]:

Comment: It takes CSS to style HTML elements inline.

Comment: Added a solution to use dynamic values with Tailwind variants @Max